# O Firebase Analytics precisa ser inciado em todas as activities?

Tags: java, android, firebase

Estou num impasse incômodo. Estou criando o costume de utilizar o Firebase no meu projeto, mas não entendo como utilizá-lo. Preciso colocar o código do Firebase Analytics em todos as *activities* ou em apenas uma?

Answer (score 1):

De acordo com as nota de [Versão 9.8 - October 24, 2016](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android) do Firebase Android SDK o **Automatic Screen Tracking** (rastreamento automático de tela) já é suportado pelo Firebase Analytics no Android, enquanto [para IOS](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/screens?hl=pt-br) já faz um tempo. Para saber mais detalhes você pode seguir as orientações na [**documentação do Firebase Analytics**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics).

Porém, uma outra alternativa para não precisar iniciar em todas *Activities*, seria criar uma variável global em uma classe que estenda a classe `Application`:

```
public class MyLittleApplication extends Application {
    public static  FirebaseAnalytics fbAnalytics;
    @Override
        public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        fbAnalytics= FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);
    }
}
```

No `manifest.xml` você usa a tag `<application >` desta forma:

```
<application
  android:name=".MyLittleApplication" ...
```